# Laravel Blade Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have the below arrays and I want to get it in laravel blade as HTML table

```
array:2 [▼
"chest" => array:2 [▼
"Chest Press" => array:1 [▼
  0 => "1"
]
"Flys" => array:2 [▼
  0 => "3"
  1 => "4"
]
]
"hints" => array:2 [▼
"Chest Press" => array:1 [▼
  0 => "test1"
]
"Flys" => array:1 [▼
  0 => "test2"
]
]
]
```

I try the below but I dont get right HTML table, its correct the first two columns but the third columnt is not, any ideas how to print it on HTML table

```
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-reflow">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Exercises</th>
                  <th>Days</th>
                  <th>Hints</th>


                </tr>
            </thead>
        <tbody>

        @foreach($chests['chest'] as $chest => $exc)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$chest}}</td>
                @foreach($exc as $key => $value)
                    <td>
                         <strong>{{$value}},</strong>
                    </td>
                @endforeach

        @endforeach

        @foreach($chests['hints'] as $hint => $hin)


                @foreach($hin as $key => $value)
                    <td>
                         <strong>{{$value}}</strong>
                    </td>

                @endforeach

              </tr>
        @endforeach

          </tbody>
```

Comment: Could you improve the info regarding the array content ?

Comment: @Hyti I edited my 1st post

Comment: Please show the structure of what currently it's is displaying and the structure you want.

Comment: I get this https://ibb.co/n4As8K but I want something like this https://ibb.co/hj6Avz

Answer (score 0):

Answered

```
        <tbody>
          @foreach ($chests['chest'] as $exerciseName => $daysArray)
              <tr>
                  <td>{{ $exerciseName }}</td>
            @foreach ($daysArray as $day)

                  <td >{{  $day }}</td>
            @endforeach
                  <td>{{ $chests['hints'][$exerciseName][0] }}</td>
              </tr>
          @endforeach

          </tbody>
```

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-blade-multidimensional-array